# Smoke Simulation - "border collision" is not working

Tags: smoke-simulation, mantaflow

I am trying to create some nice sprite sheets from blenders smoke simulation that could be used in game vfx.

But the smoke always fills up the entire smoke domain, the "border collision" should do the trick but regardless what checkmarks i set it does not make a difference.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?

**Blender Version:** 3.0.1

[image]

**[Example File (Google Drive)](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1wCzMuCLG8Jk5Xrn8CGa5hP6MN1sZeaOL/view?usp=sharing)**

Comment: If you don't want to fill domain you have to disable Collisions and/or enable Gas > Dissolve ... If you feel a sim is not updated to your adjustment change +/- 1 Divisions.

Comment: The dissolve option does work, although I'd like to compare the outcome to the border collision to see which is better. How can I disable the collision?

Comment: Go a head :) It would work almost the same here ... I mentioned that just because enabled collision is like closed box ... so a smoke can't go a way.

Comment: To clarify, it does not matter if the check marks are set or unset, the smoke always collides with the box. I just assumed from the documentation they would need to be set for the box to be "open". ^^ --> "Controls which sides of the domain will allow fluid “pass through” the domain, making it disappear without influencing the rest of the simulation, and which sides will deflect fluids"

Comment: What make you feel it collides even with "open" all sides? Fact that domain is filled by smoke is just because of really high value of Turbulence effector. If you set strength to zero or delete you can see smoke flows out of domain without collision.

Comment: Hmm..  i think you are right... i thought if the domain is "open" the smoke shouldn't stay in there and dissolve after a while...